# What is the correct command for sudo apt-get update --dry-run, which does not work?

Tags: command-line

I saw the command `sudo apt-get update --dry-run` which apparently said it should give the number of packages that need updates. However, when I run it on Ubuntu 16.04, I get `E: Command line option --dry-run is not understood in combination with the other options.`

What is the right command that will give the number of updates, preferably similar to `sudo apt-get update --dry-run?`

Comment: You probably think that `apt-get update` really updates packages? This is wrong. It checks for possible upgrades. `apt-get upgrade` really does something. You can run it with `--dry-run`. Anyway you need `apt update` first.

Answer (score 4):

This is a wrong command to get "the number of packages that need updates".

The correct command is

```
sudo apt update
```

It will check for updates and show the number like this:

```
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

Comment: This is NOT an answer. OP is looking for a dry-run on `apt-get update` which used to work on apt version 0.9.7, but is not working anymore on newer version of apt.

Comment: What do you thing `apt update` does? Why would you need to "dry-run" it?

Comment: Because `apt-get update` command sometimes has errors, so I would like to check the command (for monitoring) without having sudo rights or changing anything.

Comment: By the way, the question is about `apt-get` not `apt` (which is not always available)